# How to align subplots to the centre of the figure when number of plots are less than rowsxcolumns?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

Is it possible to align subplots to the centre of the figure when number of plots are less than rowsxcolumns? e.g;

If I use this:

```
figure
for pl=1:5
      subplot(3,2,pl)
end
```

I get this result:[image]
Can I somehow get the following output in which since last row has only one plot, it gets centre-aligned as shown below? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually update the position of any of the axes created when using subplot, e.g.

```
figure
for pl=1:5
   ax(pl) = subplot(3,2,pl)
end
% post r2014b
ax(5).Position(1) = 0.5-ax(5).Position(3)/2;
```

If your using a matlab pre r2014b you need to change the last line to the following:

```
% pre r2014b
pos = get ( ax(5), 'position' );
pos(1) = 0.5-pos(3)/2;
set ( ax(5), 'position', pos );
```